# Laravel "At Least and At Most" one field is required

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have four different fields a, b, c and d. I want only one of them to be filled. How may I do this?

I found out `required_without_all:foo,bar,...` on Laravel documentation but this seems to allow at least one field. I can fill others as well. I want only one field to be filled and one of them should be required.

This is what I did so far, but I am allowed to send these fields together.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "isFlat" => "required_without_all:isDetachedHouse,isTerrace,isSemiDetached",
        "isDetachedHouse" => "required_without_all:isFlat,isTerrace,isSemiDetached",
        "isTerrace" => "required_without_all:isFlat,isDetachedHouse,isSemiDetached",
        "isSemiDetached" => "required_without_all:isFlat,isDetachedHouse,isTerrace",
        "finishQuality" => [
            "required",
            Rule::in(["luxury", "standard", "economy"])
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Share your `$validation`

Comment: I added the code @S.Wasta

Comment: Did you try `required_without`? e.g `isFlat => required_without: isDetachedHouse, isTerrace` and so on... The definition of this is: `The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are empty or not present`

Comment: Yes, ```required_without``` doesn't work. Works only when more than 2 fields are present. I want to allow only one of four fields. And it must be required.

Comment: This will take me a while, have to start a proyect and make a form to replicate it. If you want take a look to this post https://harishtoshniwal.com/blog/2018/laravel-validate-only-one-field-required-out-of-two/ is it what you need? One of n must to be filled

Comment: Yes, I'll look at it. One of n must be filled and must be true not false. Thanks. Basically, one of these things must be true but only one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236233/discussion-between-hassan-javed-and-s-wasta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
                $validations = $request->validate([
            'text1' => [
                'bail',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (request()->filled('text2') && request()->filled("text3")) {
                        return $fail('Only 1 of the three is allowed');
                    }
                }
            ],
            "text2" => [
                'bail',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (request()->filled('text1') && request()->filled("text3")) {
                        return $fail('Only 1 of the three is allowed');
                    }
                }
            ],
            "text3" => [
                'bail',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (request()->filled('text1') && request()->filled("text2")) {
                        return $fail('Only 1 of the three is allowed');
                    }

                    if (!request()->filled('text1') && !request()->filled("text2") && !request()->filled($attribute)) {
                        return $fail('You must fill one');
                    }
                }
            ],
        ]);
```

Replace `text1`, `text2` and `text3`.

Of course you can add more validation to each `text` after `function`. You can validate if is string or number, etc... for example after function write "size:3" this will return error if you write a single character

Example:

```
//validation
'text1' => [
                'bail',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (request()->filled('text2') && request()->filled("text3")) {
                        return $fail('Only 1 of the three is allowed');
                    }
                },
               "size:3"
            ],
```

```
// I fill form with these values
text1[value="q"]
text2[value=null]
text3[value="hey"]
```

Will returns errors:

- The text1 must be 3 characters.
- Only 1 of the three is allowed

Comment: ¿Does it Works?

Comment: Sorry, I've been working on other validations. Will try today and I'll post comment.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a form with four checkboxes for the four types of housing. If you require that exactly one of those options is provided, why not use a radio-button or a select?

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="housingtype" value="flat">
    flat
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="housingtype" value="detachedHouse">
    detached house
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="housingtype" value="terrace">
    terrace
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="housingtype" value="semiDetached">
    semi-detached
</label>
```

Or with a select:

```html
<select name="housingtype">
    <option value="flat">flat</option>
    <option value="detachedHouse">detached house</option>
    <option value="terrace">terrace</option>
    <option value="semiDetached">semi-detached</option>
</select>
```

Then the validation should be like:

```php
[
    'housingtype' => 'required|in:flat,detachedHouse,terrace,semiDetached',
    // ...
]
```

One extra benefit: it is now trivial to add a housing type!

Comment: Thanks. I understand this approach. But can't use this.